# Powershell: Throws "InvalidOperation" error when calling Get-AzureRMKeyVault in Azure Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm attempting to run the following script as part of an Azure DevOps pipeline to retrieve access policies from a Keyvault however it fails on the following command

$keyVaultAccessPolicies = (Get-AzureRMKeyVault -VaultName $keyVaultName).accessPolicies

The error is: InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzureRmKeyVault], PSInvalidOperationException

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Full script is as follows:

```
param(
   [string][parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $keyVaultName
)

$keyVaultAccessPolicies = (Get-AzureRMKeyVault -VaultName $keyVaultName).accessPolicies
$armAccessPolicies = @()

if($keyVaultAccessPolicies)
{
   foreach($keyVaultAccessPolicy in $keyVaultAccessPolicies)
   {
      $armAccessPolicy = [pscustomobject]@{
         tenantId = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.TenantId
         objectId = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.ObjectId
      }

      $armAccessPolicyPermissions = [pscustomobject]@{
         keys = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToKeys
         secrets = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToSecrets
         certificates = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToCertificates
         storage = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToStorage
     }

     $armAccessPolicy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name permissions -Value $armAccessPolicyPermissions

     $armAccessPolicies += $armAccessPolicy
   }
}

$armAccessPoliciesParameter = [pscustomobject]@{
   list = $armAccessPolicies
}

$armAccessPoliciesParameter = $armAccessPoliciesParameter | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 -Compress

Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Infra.KeyVault.AccessPolicies;]$armAccessPoliciesParameter")
```

Comment: How do you run this script? Do you use [`Azure PowerShell task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: Yes, using an Azure Powershell Task within a pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `Get-AzKeyVault`  to replace the `Get-AzureRMKeyVault`.

For example:

```
$keyVaultAccessPolicies = (Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVaultName).accessPolicies
```

Here is the doc about [Get-AzKeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvault?view=azps-6.0.0)